# Make ssl-context-support conditional with tcp-connection-factory using Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, ssl, tcp, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration-ip-3.0.8.RELEASE jar for making TCP connection.
My requirement is to enable SSL support conditionally.
I am using below code to make connection with and without SSL respectively

> With SSL

```
    <beans:bean id="serverCustomSerializer"
    class="com.telnet.core.serializer.CustomSerializer">
    <beans:property name="terminatingChar"
        value="${server.terminator}" />
    <beans:property name="maxLength"
        value="${server.msgLength}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="serverFactoryTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <beans:property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="queueCapacity" value="0" />
</beans:bean>

<int:channel id="telnetLandingChannel" />

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverFactoryWithSSL"
type="server" host="${server.host}" port="${server.port}"
single-use="false" serializer="${server.serializer}"
deserializer="${server.serializer}"
task-executor="serverFactoryTaskExecutor"
ssl-context-support="sslContextSupport" />

<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="serverInboundAdpaterAck" channel="telnetLandingChannel"
    connection-factory="${server.factory}" error-channel="errorChannel"
    auto-startup="false" />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="serverOutboundAdapter" channel="serverReplyChannel"
    connection-factory="serverFactory" auto-startup="true" />
```

> Without SSL

```
<beans:bean id="serverCustomSerializer"
    class="com.telnet.core.serializer.CustomSerializer">
    <beans:property name="terminatingChar"
        value="${server.terminator}" />
    <beans:property name="maxLength"
        value="${server.msgLength}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="serverFactoryTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <beans:property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="queueCapacity" value="0" />
</beans:bean>

<int:channel id="telnetLandingChannel" />

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverFactory"
    type="server" host="${server.host}" port="${server.port}"
    single-use="false" serializer="${server.serializer}"
    deserializer="${server.serializer}"
    task-executor="serverFactoryTaskExecutor" />

<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="serverInboundAdpaterAck" channel="telnetLandingChannel"
    connection-factory="${server.factory}" error-channel="errorChannel"
    auto-startup="false" />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="serverOutboundAdapter" channel="serverReplyChannel"
    connection-factory="serverFactory" auto-startup="true" />
```

I need to use both in the same file and based upon some external flag, need to decide connection should support SSL or not as some customer wants with SSL and some wants without SSL.

Independently both are working file. 
I need advice How can I make it configurable (flag based).
TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean class has a method setSslContextSupport(TcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport), but How this can be called conditionally in xml.

Comment: 3.0.8? Really? That's four years old. You need to show the configuration that is using these factories before we can advise.

Comment: Added configuration code for tcp-connection. Is there any property/attribute by which we can disable or enable SSL while making tcp connection, like require-ssl=true

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.25.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-xml) to activate one or the other during application start up.

> Bean definition profiles is a mechanism in the core container that allows for registration of different beans in different environments. The word environment can mean different things to different users and this feature can help with many use cases, including: ...

**EDIT**

If you just want to convert the connection factory to Java config, just add a `<bean/>` of this type to your xml. If you want to convert everything to Java configuration, refer to the Spring Integration reference manual.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean serverFactoryWithOrWithoutSSL(
            @Value("${server.host}") String host,
            @Value("${server.port}") int port,
            @Value("${use.ssl}") boolean useSSL,
            ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer serializer,
            TcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport) {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fb = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean("server");
        fb.setHost(host);
        fb.setPort(port);
        fb.setSerializer(serializer);
        fb.setDeserializer(serializer);
        if (useSSL) {
            fb.setSslContextSupport(sslContextSupport);
        }
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    public ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer serializer() {
        return new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport() {
        return new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport("file:keyStore.ks", "secret", "file:trustStore", "secret");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, but does spring provide an inbuilt option to enable/disable SSL connection?

Comment: Not with XML configuration, when using Java configuration (`@Bean`) you can conditionally set the `ssl-context-support`. With XML configuration, you must add 2 beans and put them in different profiles.

Comment: Gary, can you please share any link with Java Configuration for quick reference.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; but you really should try to upgrade to a newer version; the current version is 5.2.1.